# How to receive JSON POST request in Laravel

Tags: json, laravel, request, fetch

I want to POST Fetch to my backend Laravel server from my React-Native mobile app.I dont know wihch parts is missing or what I'm doing wrong.. Here is the fetch :

```
fetch('http://example.com/react_test', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json',
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: inputName,
                email: inputEmail,
                phone: inputPhone
            }),
        }).then((response) => response.json())
            .then((responseJson) => {
                alert(JSON.stringify(responseJson))
            }).catch((error) => {
                alert(error);
        });
```

I receive data in my backend like this with POST route

> Route::post('/react_test', 'QuestionController@index');

```
public function index($request){

        $n = $request->input('name');

        DB::table('admin_panels')->insert(['discord' => $n, 'twitter' => 'anan']);

        return response('helal');

    }
```

and I get this error :

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \
>   MethodNotAllowedHttpException No message

Comment: I don't see any `cross origin resource sharing` configured in the above. Based on your description of `I want to post from my react native app to my laravel app` this would be a requirement.

Comment: how I can add them properly, maybe write it as answer so if it will work I can accept it as answer

Comment: I checked as you say and added to Header 
'Access-Control-Allow-Origin':'',
'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' , now it doesnt give any error but after some time it gives Network Failed Request Error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all you need to ignore verifying csrf field for that route.

In your **app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php**

```
protected $except = [
    '/react_test',
];
```

Secondly use argument as Request in your index method.

```
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function index(Request $request){

    $n = $request->input('name');

    DB::table('admin_panels')->insert(['discord' => $n, 'twitter' => 'anan']);

    return response('helal');

}
```

Comment: OK I will check these and let you know :) Thank you!

Comment: Woooow, it worked!!! Thank you so much! So this is the way I should do when I need to use POST request yes?

Comment: I keep working about it and wanted to ask you. You think ignoring verifying csrf token could cause some security issues?

Comment: @Berke Yes ignoring csrf token can cause some security issues. Request from any unknown sources are also accepted. You must be careful about it.

Comment: I just dont get how they could find the url's which im using for example?

Comment: @Berke there are many ways to find urls. Browsers helps us to find urls from Network section. And your javascript source is easily available to every clients.

Comment: Hmm if you say so.. Do you think which securities I should use then? Would you suggest me something about it?

Comment: Actually the thing we need to manage that when user logs in we should give him some unique token and next requests will be made with that token right? Thats the thing?

Comment: @Berke Simple security will be you save save session in before loading your page, and check that session in your method. Or use can load you csrf token to meta tag and retrieve it using javascript/jquery.
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}"> &
headers: {
        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
    }